# Chebyshev’s theorem

Tags: probability

Suppose the mean noon-time temperature for September days in San Diego is 24∘ and the standard deviation is 4.9. (Temperature in this problem is measured in degrees celsius)

On September 26, 1963, the all-time record of noon-time temperature in San Diego of 44∘ was hit. Assume the temperature distribution is symmetric around the mean, what is the Chebyshev bound for the probability of breaking (or tieing) this record?

I am having a hard time understanding this. Could someone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chebyshev’s inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538940/chebyshevs-inequality)

Comment: Please do not repost your own questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the bound on probability provided by Chebyshev, which states that

$$
Pr(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma)\leq \frac{1}{k^2}
$$
which, in English, says that the probability that the deviation of the random variable $X$ from its expectation by more than $k$ times the standard deviation is less than 1 over this same constant $k$, but this time squared.

In your case, $\mu=24$ and $\sigma=4.9$. You want to know:

$$
Pr(X\geq 44)=Pr(X-24\geq 20)
$$

So then,
$$
k\sigma=20\Leftrightarrow k=\frac{20}{4.9}
$$

Note, however, that in the first equation we have

$$
Pr(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma)=2Pr(X-\mu\geq k\sigma)
$$
since you have a symmetric distribution and $X$ can deviate in either direction. Combining this:

$$
Pr(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma)\leq \frac{1}{k^2} \Longrightarrow 2Pr\left(X-24\geq 20\right)\leq \frac{1}{\left(\frac{20}{4.9}\right)^2}\\
\Longrightarrow Pr\left(X-24\geq 20\right)\leq \frac{1}{2\left(\frac{20}{4.9}\right)^2}\approx 0.03
$$

Answer (score 0):

$P(X\geq 44) = P(X-24 \geq 20) \leq \frac{E(X-24)^2}{20^2} = \frac{4.9^2}{400} \leq \frac{25}{400} = 16^{-1}$

Comment: I think it should be $(2*16)^{-1}$. The inequality is with the absolute value of $X-24$, i.e. $Pr(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma)$.