# Chebyshev Theorem question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose the mean noon-time temperature for September days in San Diego is $24^{∘}$ and the standard deviation is $3.2$. (Temperature in this problem is measured in degrees celsius).

Using Chebyshev’s theorem, what is the minimal probability (in percents) that the noon-time temperature of a september days is between $17.6^{∘}$ and $30.4^{∘}$?
A.

On September 26, 1963, the all-time record of noon-time temperature in San Diego of $44^{∘}$ was hit. Assume the temperature distribution is symmetric around the mean, what is the Chebyshev bound for the probability of breaking (or tieing) this record?
B.

Comment: This is very similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539017/chebyshevs-theorem. Are you in the same class?

Answer (score 0):

Chebyshev's inequality tells us: the probability  that $X$ differs more than $n\cdot\sigma$ from the mean is no more than $1/n^2$.  Now, for your first question, $n$ certainly is $2$.  Do you see this?  Hence the probability that the temperature differs *more* than $2\sigma$ is less than $1/2^2$.  Can you work out from here?